# Ask user to enter a positive integer n and use this number to calculate the sum of series up to n term

Tags: python

Ask user to enter a positive integer n and use this number to calculate the sum of series up to n term. (20 pts)
Test case:

- if n = 2 the series will become 3 + 33 = 36
- if n = 5 the series will become 3 + 33 + 333 + 3333 + 33333 = 37035

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: # input user
n = input('Enter a number:')
sum_of_series = 0
var = 3
for i sum of series:
    sum_of_series += var
    var = var * 10 + 3
print('Sum of series"' + n + '"is:' ,sum_of_series)

Comment: Please add your code to your question, not in a comment (and format as a code block).

Comment: Your problem is not the algorithm, but likely your for loop and the fact that `n` will be a string. Try `for _ in range(int(n)):`.

Comment: # input user
n = input('Enter a number:')
sum_of_series = 0
var =3
for i in range(int(n)):
    sum_of_series += var
var = var * 10 + 3
print('Sum of series"' + n + '"is:' ,sum_of_series)
so this is what it should've been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to think about the number of times each digits place is added.

For instance, at `n=5`, you are adding the 3 in the units place 5 times, but adding the 3 in the ten thousands place only once. Because of this, it is appropriate to start the for loop at 5 and decrement as we add everything up together.

```
n = input("Please enter a number. ")
total = 0
for i in range(int(n),0,-1):
    total += 3*i*(10**(int(n)-i))

print(total)
```

I am using math.pow to go to the next place (i.e. 1, 10, 100, etc.). I do int(n)-i because I want to start at 0 and go up to n for this exponent.

Output:

```
Please enter a number. 5
37035.0
```

**Edit:** I changed syntax to use Python's syntax for exponents instead of math.pow

Comment: So I am still having issue Name error issue with the math.pow

Comment: @AaliyaBobb I changed it so we no longer need to use the math module. See if it works for you now.

Comment: I have 3 more question can i get your help also?

Comment: @AaliyaBobb Glad I can help. If this answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark so that future users will know. You can ask new questions.

Comment: Write a Python program that keeps prompting the user for odd numbers by using a loop. Enter an even number to terminate the loop. Calculate & display the average of all the odd numbers.

Comment: # User input
n = input('Enter an odd number then an even number terminate the loop:')
odd_numbers = 0
for i in range (int(n)):
    if (n%2 != 1):
        total = total +  1
print('Average of the odd number is"' + n + '"is:', odd_numbers)

Comment: @AaliyaBobb You should ask the new questions separately. Comments are usually only for clarification purposes and I think these will get deleted after moderation looks over.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function that adds a 3 at the end using 10x + 3:

```
def function3(seed):
   if(seed==1):
      return 3
   else:
      return (10*f3(seed-1))+3
seed = int(input('integer please:  '));
print(function3(seed))
```

We could also build a string which could be regarded as cheating if we're talking about a function.
Here is an alternative definition for the function:

```
def function3(seed):
   s = ""
   for i in range(0,seed):
       s+="3"
   return s
```